# React-Datepicker: showTimeSelect margins not aligning correctly

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui-react, react-datepicker

As the title states, the margins on my `react-datepicker`'s time div look wonky.  I'm using the `react-datepicker` npm package on version 1.2.2 (which should be the latest version of it).  I've included the css for it like so in my root component where my app initializes: `import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker-cssmodules.css";`

My `react-datepicker` component is wrapped in the semantic-ui-react `Form.Field` component, however the css on the time picker is still wonky even if I remove this `Form.Field` from wrapping it.

Here's what my code looks like:

```
                <Grid.Column>
                  <Form.Field error={!!fieldErrors.date}>
                    <label>
                      Label
                    </label>
                    <DatePicker
                      name="date"
                      selected={fields.date}
                      onChange={onDateChange}
                      showTimeSelect
                      timeIntervals={15}
                    />
                    <InlineError error={fieldErrors.date} />
                  </Form.Field>
                </Grid.Column>
```

And here's what the UI looks like:

[image]

Thank you for your time.

Edit:

[image: Styles]

Comment: It seems like 2 different CSS are colluding. Which classes / properties are applied to it?

Comment: `.react-datepicker__time-container .react-datepicker__time .react-datepicker__time-box ul.react-datepicker__time-list` I'll make an edit to the main post to show the styles being applied to it.

Comment: a/ It seems like there is an `!important` somewhere overriding this css (as the un-applied `padding: 5px 10px;` shows). But what ? 
b/ I'd say it is the main component "fault". A wrong global width may-be ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this style worked for me:

```
.react-datepicker__time-container   .react-datepicker__time  
.react-datepicker__time-box   ul.react-datepicker__time-list {  
     padding: 0; 
}
```